# The prefix "sonar" for element "sonar:sonar" is not bound

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I have a build.xml-file that looks something like this:

```
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" classpath="/path/sonar-ant-task.jar"/>

<target name="sonar">       
    <sonar:sonar/>
</target>
```

And when I run the file I get:

```
The prefix "sonar" for element "sonar:sonar" is not bound.
```

Any obvious things I'm missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're missing the namespace declaration in the top `project` element of your Ant script.

`xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant"` ought to do it.

Comment: Is it possible to use the sonar ant task in any way without the specific sonar namespace?

Comment: Ant-contrib, at least, can be brought in with no namespace declaration, then you can invoke its tasks like `<try> ... </try>` with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

In ant you can not use  .
try below and if you are setting any properties use key value pare in xml tag.
To allocate value use attributes of xml tags.

```
 <sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

</sonar:sonar>
```

Comment: Why in earth are you repeating an already given answer? If you agree an answer, just upvote it instead of repeating it. Stack Overflow isn't an old fashioned discussion forum wherein everyone repeats each other into an undigestable mess upon (dis)agreement. Stack Overflow is a clean Question & Answer site wherein everyone can vote each other upon (dis)agreement.