# Ant using antlib with namespace

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

I am using the following demonstration script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" basedir="." xmlns:deploy="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">
    <target name="default">
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        <deploy:if>
            <isset property="defaultprop"/>
            <then>
                <echo message="it's set!"/>
            </then>
        </deploy:if>
    </target>
</project>
```

When I run this build script (with target `default`), the error is

```
build.xml:9: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:net.sf.antcontrib:if
```

The pathelement `lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar` exists, and ant is picking it up. I'm thinking the problem is how I'm using the xmlns. I'm taking this from another example that I have that also doesn't work for me (it works on a particular server, though!), and trying to figure out what the magic sauce is.

Comment: Indeed xmlns looks a bit out of place, have you tried without it ? The rest looks ok. You can also move the taskdef out of the target

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Thanks for the question. When I remove the `xmlns=...` bit and the two `deploy:`s, the example works. With these two bits, though, the whole thing works on a server we have, so I'm trying to recreate the namespace version on my machine.

Comment: Have you tried with `xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib"` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your taskdef where you're adding ant-contrib needs to declare a URI the same as the namespace you're defining and prefixing in the project.  Similar to how the taskdef [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860024/the-prefix-sonar-for-element-sonarsonar-is-not-bound) works.

```
<project name="test" basedir="." xmlns:deploy="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">
    <target name="default">
        <taskdef uri="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib" resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        <deploy:if>
            <isset property="defaultprop"/>
            <then>
                <echo message="it's set!"/>
            </then>
        </deploy:if>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Can you think of any way that it could succeed without this modification?

Comment: If you threw away the uri from the taskdef, and the xmlns declaration at the project level, the tasks end up in the default namespace, so you can call them like `<if>` instead of `<prefix:if>`.  Prefixes are handy for keeping things with conflicting names from colliding, much like packages in java, and also serve to at-a-glance identify where some functionality is coming from.

Comment: I understand that, but this example has the `xmlns`, and `<deploy:if>`, but no URI with the taskdef...and it works!! It works on some server to which I don't have full access, so I'm unable to make a close investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error has `if` on the end, and it's talking about line 9. I think it's a problem with the syntax of this tag:

```
    <deploy:if>
```

I can't find any documentation on a "deploy:if" tag, or even a "deploy" tag. **I think there is no 'deploy' task in Ant - you need to make a 'deploy' *target***.

How about trying this:

```
  <if>
    <isset property="defaultprop"/>
    <then>
      <antcall target="deploy" />
    </then>
  </if>
```

As I read it, this will check the isset, then call the "deploy" target if it's set.
Of course, you need to make the 'deploy' target now :)

Comment: The 'if' task comes from ant-contrib, which OP has defined in a taskdef, and he wants the tasks to live in the namespace prefix 'deploy'.

Comment: Okay, but I don't think he did anything to put it there.